# What exactly is meant by "true in all interpretations"?

Tags: logic, model-theory

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula) defines a valid formula as:

> A formula of a formal language is a valid formula if and only if it is true under every possible interpretation of the language.

I'm trying to understand what "every possible interpretation" really means. Here is my attempt:

The term 'interpretation' is defined in the book *Model Theory* by M. Manzano ([link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Nc5uXx057JwC&lpg=PA5&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=true)):

[image]

It is probably easier to split into three different definitions (not sure why author combines them):

> **Interpretation:** An interpretation is a pair $( \mathfrak M, \mathfrak I)$, where $\mathfrak M$ is a structure and $\mathfrak I$ is an assignment in $\mathfrak M$.
>
> **Value of terms:** Given an interpretation $( \mathfrak M, \mathfrak I)$ and a term $\tau$, $\rm val_{\mathfrak M, \mathfrak I} (\tau)$ = ... [add the usual piecewise definition]
>
> **Satisfaction relation:** Given an interpretation $(\mathfrak M, \mathfrak I)$ and a wff $\varphi$, $(\mathfrak M, \mathfrak I) \models \varphi$ iff ... [add the usual definition]

Q1. I hope these are the commonly used definitions, and not my misunderstanding.

Now the only part left is determining which all interpretations are included:

Let $\rm A_n$ be the signature (set of non-logical symbols) of our formal language, $\mathfrak M$ a structure and $I_{\mathfrak M}$ its interpretation function. Then I'm guessing:

1. If $\rm dom(I_{\mathfrak M}) \subset \rm A_n$, then interpretations based on $\mathfrak M$ are not included in "all interpretations", since it cannot interpret all non-logical symbols.
2. If $\rm dom(I_{\mathfrak M}) = \rm A_n$, then interpretations based on $\mathfrak M$ are included in "all interpretations".
3. If $\rm dom(I_{\mathfrak M}) \supset \rm A_n$, then interpretations based on $\mathfrak M$ are included in "all interpretations", since the definitions of value of terms and satisfaction allow it.

Q2. Is this understanding correct?

Q3. Wouldn't it be clearer to define the set of applicable interpretations for the formal language, rather than leave "every possible interpretation" undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A first-order signature $L$ consists of function symbols and relation symbols.
- An $L$-structure $\mathfrak{M}$ consists of a set $M$ and interpretations of all of the symbols in $L$ as functions and relations on $M$.
- An $L$-interpretation consists of an $L$-structure $\mathfrak{M}$ and an assignment $\mathfrak{I}$ of variables to elements of $\mathfrak{M}$.
- Given an $L$-interpretation $(\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{I})$, we have a definition of what it means for this interpretation to satisfy an $L$-formula $\varphi$.
- We say an $L$-formula $\varphi$ is valid if it is satisfied by all $L$-interpretations.

The point is that everything is done relative to a fixed signature $L$. At the end of your question, it seems like you're worrying about interpretations involving $L'$-structures where $L'\neq L$. You don't need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for providing clear definitions. Just to confirm (I prefer your more consistent notation, but I'm using mine as defined above just to double check), you're saying that interpretations based on a structure $\mathfrak M$ are considered in the phrase "true in all interpretations" iff $\rm dom(I_{\mathfrak M}) = \rm A_n$? In your notation, an $L$-structure interprets all *and only* $L$-symbols?

Comment: Yes, that's what $L$-structure means!

Comment: But note: If $L'\subsetneq L$, then it doesn't make any sense to ask whether an $L$-formula is true in an $L'$-structure. On the other hand, if $L\subsetneq L'$, then every $L'$-structure can be viewed as an $L$ structure by "forgetting" about the meaning of the symbols in $L'\setminus L$ (this is called taking the *reduct* to $L$). So it makes sense to ask whether and $L$-formula is true in an $L'$-structure - but the interpretations of the symbols in $L'\setminus L$ are totally irrelevant, i.e. we might as well just be looking at the reduct to $L$.

Comment: Yes if $L \subset L'$, the reduct to $L$ of an $L′$-structure would be contained in the class of $L$-structures anyway. Now it makes sense why we only look at $L$-structures.

Comment: prev comment contd... Just wanted to add for any beginner reading: the $L$-formula would true in the $L'$-structure (in the sense explained by Alex) iff it is true in the reduct to $L$. Hence, my comment that we only need to look at $L$-structures, since that tells us about the truth value (in the sense explained by Alex) in all the larger $L'$-structures as well.